# For Each file doesn't go beyond 1000 files?

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject

I'm trying to get a CSV output for a Blender render job duration estimation. I like to input file time stamps into an Excel, so I wrote below VBScript (it's not 100% ready, but the echo should work). However, it won't iterate beyond the 1000th png file. It ends at file 9999.
Currently I got 35432 png files.

Why won't VBScript go beyond 1000 files?

```
Option Explicit 'force all variables to be declared
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objTS 'Text Stream Object
Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\tmp\output.txt", ForWriting, True)

Recurse objFSO.GetFolder("C:\tmp")
objTS.Close()

Sub Recurse(objFolder)
    Dim objFile, objSubFolder
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "png" Then
            WScript.Echo objFSO.GetBaseName(objFile.Name) & vbTab & _
                CDate(objFile.DateLastModified) & vbTab & _
                CDate(objFile.DateCreated)
            objTS.WriteLine(objfile.Path)
        End If
    Next
    'unmark to make it recursive
    'For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
    '    Recurse objSubFolder
    'Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Just guessing, but unless your file names have some kind of left padding, and as by default they are iterated in alphabetic order (I'm supossing your file system is NTFS) then in a set of 35432 files the last one is the 9999 (alphabetic order).

Comment: i just echo them the look is that it counts from 1 to 9999 (al files are named like 12345.png

Comment: Silly question, but, did you count the number of lines in the output? If the files are named `1.png`, `2.png`, ..., `12345.png` and as said the files are processed in *alphabetic* order (`100.png` < `9.png`) with a set of 35000 files the last set of files echoed will be `9.png`, `90.png`, `91.png`, ... `900.png` ... `9998.png`, `9999.png` as everyting starting with a `9` is alphabetically greater.